# Converting SQL server table data from a column structure to a different column structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have just taken over development at my place a work and have basically been thrown in the deep end with the SQL server, i'm not very knowledgeable with query's and the format so please go easy on me.

i'm using Microsoft SQL server 2012 and basically what i'm trying to achieve is to take data from one database table reformat it into a different structure then import this into a new database. I've been given the code below from the developers who created the software. i have a basic understanding of what it is doing but i'm getting a fair few errors i cant seem to trace no matter what i fix and need a little bit of help making sure is formatted correctly as the devs take a long time to answer any email questions

```
--Specify the database, table and columns we want to insert into
INSERT INTO new_database.dbo.QuizQuestions (uuid, [type], question, answer, created_date, modified_date,
master_category, master_decade, master_difficulty, is_editable, is_deletable, media)

--Get the data from the old database (old_database) and map the media filename to the media2 table in the new database

select 
   questions.uuid, 
   questions.newtype, 
   questions.QuestionText, 
   questions.AnswerText, 
   questions.CreatedDate, 
   questions.ModifiedDate, 
   questions.master_category, 
   questions.master_decade, 
   questions.master_difficulty,
   questions.IsEditable, 
   questions.IsDeletable,
   media.id as mediaid 
from
(
   select NEWID() as uuid, 
   CASE 
          WHEN qqt.TypeName = 'Sound' THEN 'Audio'
          ELSE qqt.TypeName
   END AS newtype,
   qq.QuestionText, qq.AnswerText, 
   qq.CreatedDate, 
   CASE 
          WHEN qq.ModifiedDate is NOT NULL THEN qq.ModifiedDate
          ELSE GETDATE()
   END as ModifiedDate, 
   CASE
          WHEN cat.id is NOT NULL THEN cat.id
          ELSE 1
   END as master_category,
   qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID as master_decade,
   qd.id as master_difficulty,
   qq.IsEditable, qq.IsDeletable,
   qq.FilePath,
   SUBSTRING(
          qq.FilePath, 
          len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2, 
          (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - 1) as fname
   --len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath)) as positionoflastdot,
   --len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) as positionoflastslash
   from old_database.dbo.QuizQuestion qq
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionType qqt on qq.QuizQuestionTypeID = qqt.QuizQuestionTypeID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionDifficulty qqd on qq.QuizQuestionDifficultyID = qqd.QuizQuestionDifficultyID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqc on qq.QuizQuestionCategoryID = qqc.QuizQuestionCategoryID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionDecade qqdc on qq.QuizQuestionDecadeID = qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqmc on qq.MasterCategoryID = qqmc.MasterQuestionCategoryID
   left join old_database_Demo.dbo.QuizCategories cat on qqc.CategoryName = cat.name
   left join old_database_Demo.dbo.QuizDifficulties qd on qd.id = qq.MasterDifficultyID
   where qq.MasterCategoryID is not null
) as questions
left join new_database.dbo.Media2 media on media.name = REPLACE(fname,'QUIZ','')
```

at first i was getting

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.
```

so I've added moved the media from the end of the line and put it next to answers 
and adjusted the select list to match as this is how the table is structured

```
--Specify the database, table and columns we want to insert into
INSERT INTO new_database.dbo.QuizQuestions (uuid, [type], question, answer,  media, created_date, modified_date,
master_category, master_decade, master_difficulty, is_editable, is_deletable)

--Get the data from the old database (old_database) and map the media filename to the media2 table in the new database

select 
   questions.uuid, 
   questions.newtype, 
   questions.QuestionText, 
   questions.AnswerText,
   media.id as mediaid, 
   questions.CreatedDate, 
   questions.ModifiedDate, 
   questions.master_category, 
   questions.master_decade, 
   questions.master_difficulty,
   questions.IsEditable, 
   questions.IsDeletable,

 from
(
   select NEWID() as uuid, 
   CASE 
          WHEN qqt.TypeName = 'Sound' THEN 'Audio'
          ELSE qqt.TypeName
   END AS newtype,
   qq.QuestionText, qq.AnswerText, 
   qq.CreatedDate, 
   CASE 
          WHEN qq.ModifiedDate is NOT NULL THEN qq.ModifiedDate
          ELSE GETDATE()
   END as ModifiedDate, 
   CASE
          WHEN cat.id is NOT NULL THEN cat.id
          ELSE 1
   END as master_category,
   qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID as master_decade,
   qd.id as master_difficulty,
   qq.IsEditable, qq.IsDeletable,
   qq.FilePath,
   SUBSTRING(
          qq.FilePath, 
          len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2, 
          (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - 1) as fname
   --len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath)) as positionoflastdot,
   --len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) as positionoflastslash
   from old_database.dbo.QuizQuestion qq
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionType qqt on qq.QuizQuestionTypeID = qqt.QuizQuestionTypeID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionDifficulty qqd on qq.QuizQuestionDifficultyID = qqd.QuizQuestionDifficultyID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqc on qq.QuizQuestionCategoryID = qqc.QuizQuestionCategoryID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionDecade qqdc on qq.QuizQuestionDecadeID = qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID
   left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqmc on qq.MasterCategoryID = qqmc.MasterQuestionCategoryID
   left join old_database_Demo.dbo.QuizCategories cat on qqc.CategoryName = cat.name
   left join old_database_Demo.dbo.QuizDifficulties qd on qd.id = qq.MasterDifficultyID
   where qq.MasterCategoryID is not null
) as questions
left join new_database.dbo.Media2 media on media.name = REPLACE(fname,'QUIZ','')
```

now when i execute im getting

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 55
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

this is where i'm currently stuck and have no idea how to move forward to get this to execute correctly and I've googled and researched allot i even had our customer database guy who deals with access to take a look and hes just a puzzled as i am.

any help to show me where i'm going wrong would be great

best regards
dan

Comment: i forgot to add that iv'e re-named the true database names to new_database and old_database as their names are the branding of the old  and new software.

Comment: Which version did you post? The version with the first error you listed or the second error?

Comment: sorry I've forgot to add what server i was using i'm new to this, its Microsoft SQL server 2012 and the the version I've posted was the one with the first error i found out it wasn't reflecting the column structure so changed the queryand ill add it to the post what I've changed

Comment: have you talked with the developers that gave you this code about the errors ?

Comment: I've tried multiple ways but they are not very good a getting back to me quickly. ive been trying to fix this myself and with them for about a month the problem i think is there were quite a few that did things with this.

Comment: This line -> filename to the media2 table in the new database <- 
should be a comment like the one immediately above it. You should properly qualify the fname reference in the outer join ON clause with the appropriate qq alias (which is just a best practice, not an error). Try that and see what happens. And ALWAYS wrap something like this in a transaction which you rollback - just in case something **bad** happens. A backup is also a good thing to do before you attempt in changes in a production database.

Comment: Start commenting out chunks of the query until you have one that works.   Then add things back one at a time until you find the line that causes the error.   For starters, what do you get if you run JUST the `questions` subquery?

Comment: i think i' made a error in posting the query the line you have referred to should be part of the comment above it not on a separate line. its my first time posting so not that confident how to format text correctly ill edit to correct it.

Comment: where does the questions subquery start and end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would investigate the results of the Len and Charindex functions within the Substring function.

Perhaps echo them out in a separate query. 
The 'Invalid Length' error suggests that a part of a string is being searched for using incorrect criteria.

for example..

```
    len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2
```

if the result of

```
charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2
```

is greater than the result of...

```
len(qq.FilePath)
```

then you will be trying to find a part of a string (substring) using a negative number - so if the result of the above is -2 for example, you will be asking for a -2 characters from FilePath...this is an invalid length parameter that you've passed to substring.

I would run this...

```
Select   
len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2 as 'SubStrStartPos', 
(len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - 1 as 'NoOfChars'

from old_database.dbo.QuizQuestion qq
 left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionType qqt on qq.QuizQuestionTypeID = qqt.QuizQuestionTypeID
 left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionDifficulty qqd on qq.QuizQuestionDifficultyID = qqd.QuizQuestionDifficultyID
left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqc on qq.QuizQuestionCategoryID = qqc.QuizQuestionCategoryID
left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionDecade qqdc on qq.QuizQuestionDecadeID = qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID
left join old_database.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqmc on qq.MasterCategoryID = qqmc.MasterQuestionCategoryID
left join old_database_Demo.dbo.QuizCategories cat on qqc.CategoryName = cat.name
left join old_database_Demo.dbo.QuizDifficulties qd on qd.id = qq.MasterDifficultyID
where qq.MasterCategoryID is not null
```

and check the results for negative values, troubleshoot and amend the substring.

Comment: This helped a great deal and new insight gained thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the query to work by placing the from at the end of the select list instead of underneath,

```
select 
   questions.uuid, 
   questions.newtype, 
   questions.QuestionText, 
   questions.AnswerText,
   media.id as mediaid, 
   questions.CreatedDate, 
   questions.ModifiedDate, 
   questions.master_category, 
   questions.master_decade, 
   questions.master_difficulty,
   questions.IsEditable, 
   questions.IsDeletable from
(
```

and also changing from `-1` to `-0` on the subquery to remove any negative values

```
select
(len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2),`

`(len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - 0) as fname
```

but it didn't map the media files correctly and returned null to the media column in the new table but i can work around this.

Thank you to everyone who posted for your help.